# has to or have to or should

Tags: grammar

5. Mha (have) to revise. The exams are about to start. (Correct the verb between the brackets)

I'am confused what should  I write between these two answers 
 Ali has to revise. The exams are about to start. 
or
Ali should revise. The exams are about to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options are correct.

To say **Ali has to revise** means that it is necessary for him to do so.

To say **Ali should revise** means that he ought to do so in order to prepare for the exam.

So they mean much the same thing. The first statement requires Ali to revise, the second statement merely advises him to revise.

There is no way of knowing which answer the examiner prefers.